# Symfony: An exception occured in driver: could not find driver with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, windows, symfony

I'm trying to connect with my DB (mysql) which is running on a server (docker). I'm programming on Windows.

In my symfony project I have done the following: 
parameters.yml

-> filled in the correct parameters

config.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
```

php.ini

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
```

After all of this I get the following error: `An exception occured in driver: could not find driver`

Anyone who can help since I have tried some solutions that were provided but none worked or were for linux systems.

Comment: Is MySQL or MariaDB installed? Or maybe you are using XAMPP? Can you clarify?

Comment: MySQL is installed as a docker on my server. So I want to connect to that. I'm not using XAMPP or WAMP.. I start the symfony project using: `php bin/console server:run`

Comment: Try generating `phpinfo()` and seeing if you have `mysqlnd` enabled. Or just type `php -m` in your `cmd` and look for it. That should the default since `php 5.4`. Btw, which version of PHP is that?

Comment: It's enabled. I'm using php 7.1.2

Comment: Do I need to generate a database scheme with doctorine or is that just for a local one.

Answer (score 26):

You must install mysql :

```
sudo apt install php-mysql
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I made a very stupid mistake. I was editing the php.ini file, but I didn't renamed it to php.ini (it was php.ini-prod). Afterwards I just had to put the correct path in extension_dir and it's working.

Hopefully this helps others.

Answer (score 3):

comment this line in your `.env` file. `yourproject/.env`

```
#DATABASE_URL="postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"file
```

and delete `#` in first of your mysql config code

set your username and password in this part

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://usename:password@127.0.0.1:3306/test?serverVersion=5.7"
```

Comment: That's it. Default instlalations activates postregl and I never installed it. I use mariadb

Answer (score 3):

I was having this problem on my docker environment using the `php:8.1-fpm-alpine` image and Symfony 6. I fixed it by adding the following line to my Dockerfile:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

In case this helps others: I've encountered the same problem, when running a command that needed the database (such as `bin/console make:migration`), but for a totally different reason. I was running the command from my computer instead of running it *inside* the php container. Running it inside the php container solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was a missing `i` at the end of `mysql` as found on a tutorial online, since on my PC I have the `mysqli` PHP's extension enabled instead of `mysql`, which is long deprecated by now.

So I edited the Symfony's `.env.local` `DATABASE_URL` entry this way:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysqli://youruser:yourpasswd@127.0.0.1:3306/yourdbname"
```

Just mind the first part with `mysqli`, other data is dependent on your setup.